# Android Open CV image Contrast

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to give contrast on image with the help of open cv but i don't know how to apply it after i get the picture snapped from camera then on the resulting image view i need to apply contrast with help of open cv please can any one tell me how should i do it

```
private void captureImage() {
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}


private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {

        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);

        imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now after i get the image in my imgPreview (ImageView). i need to apply contrast from open cv can please any one help me out with a code snippet.

Comment: You should check and make sure you understand the opencv4android code tutorials first.